# Sum all values in column return highest

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I'm having a small SQL problem - as I often do :P

How can I **just** return the highest summed amount out of all columns?

```
+-------+------+
| TYPE  |  VAL | Dog sums to 6    
|-------+------| Frog sums to 5 
| Cat   |    2 | Cat sums to 5
|-------|------| 
| Dog   |    3 |  
|-------|------| 
| Dog   |    3 | 
|-------|------|
| Cat   |    2 | 
|-------|------|
| Cat   |    1 |
|-------|------|
| Frog  |    5 | 
+-------+------+
```

For instance, from the table above I just want to return  -

```
+-------+------+
| TYPE  |  VAL |    
|-------+------| 
| Dog   |    6 | 
+-------+------+
```

How could I sum all columns, and then return the one with the highest summed value?

Thanks for your time

Comment: And if it's a tie, e.g. 6 cats instead of 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `group by`to calculate the value and then `order by` and `limit` to get the one you want:

```
select type, sum(val) as sumval
from table t
group by type
order by sumval desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Er, I'm not entirely sure how to say this - but I think I love you <3